# Sending emails to add information to a Website

Tags: email

I am looking out how to build a functionnality similar to what exists in Basecamp e.g. a user can add information to a thread by sending an email to a scripted email adress.

Would be nice if you could point me to right direction.

Thanks !

Comment: Are you talking about creating a mailing list?  What functionality do you want to build?  Can you build anything?  What languages are you dealing with?  What software are you capable of using?  What types of server(s) are you using?  How much demand are you expecting?  There's a reason there's already software made out there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use CodeIgniter, I would like to build an online app where users can keep track of the emails they send when they apply for a job by adding in cci a specific email adress

Comment: http://lamsonproject.org/ <-- that one's pretty cool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, I did my research and found out that 2 companies offer inbound email parsing : SendGrid and PostMark.

I'll use one of them instead of figuring out how to develop everything by myself.

Thanks for the inputs!

Romain